# Entity relationship diagram fields combination unicity representation

Tags: database, postgresql, architecture, entity-relationship

I am trying to represent my database model in an Entity Relationship diagram, I have a table that consists of the following fields:

- id: Primary key
- field_1: Foreign key
- field_2: Foreign key
- field_3
- field_4

The combination of `field_1`, `field_2`, and `field_3` should be unique.
I have already tried something like this:
[image]

I have looked on the internet and I couldn't find an answer, how can I represent the unicity of fields combination using the conventions of Entity-Relationship diagram?

Answer (score 0):

When I add a unique constraint to a table in addition to its `PK`, I annotate the columns as `AK` for "Alternate Key".